# Limit iteration of inner for-each loop in XSLT - without <xsl:copy>

Tags: xml, xslt

With reference to my previous post [Limit iteration of inner for-each loop in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444444/limit-iteration-of-inner-for-each-loop-in-xslt), asking another question about mapping to specific field instead of using  element.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Loop_Pro>
  <Pro>
    <ProID>PRO101</ProID>
    <Loop_Sub>
      <Sub>
        <SubID>SUB101</SubID>
        <Loop_CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM101</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM101N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM101N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM102</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM102N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM102N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM103</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM103N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM103N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM104</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM104N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM104N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
        </Loop_CLM>
      </Sub>
      <Sub>
        <SubID>SUB102</SubID>
        <Loop_CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM201</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM201N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM201N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM202</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM202N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM202N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM203</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM203N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM203N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
        </Loop_CLM>
      </Sub>
      <Sub>
        <SubID>SUB103</SubID>
        <Loop_CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM301</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM301N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM301N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM302</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM302N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM302N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM303</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM303N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM303N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM304</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM304N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM304N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM305</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM305N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM305N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
        </Loop_CLM>
      </Sub>
    </Loop_Sub>
  </Pro>
  <Pro>
    <ProID>PRO102</ProID>
    <Loop_Sub>
      <Sub>
        <SubID>SUB202</SubID>
        <Loop_CLM>
          <CLM>
            <CLMID>CLM201</CLMID>
            <nextfield1>CLM101N1</nextfield1>
            <nextfield2>CLM101N2</nextfield2>
          </CLM>
        </Loop_CLM>
      </Sub>
    </Loop_Sub>
  </Pro>
</Loop_Pro>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:variable name="CLMGroupOccur">2</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="/Loop_Pro">
    <OB_X1>
      <xsl:for-each select="Pro">
        <xsl:copy>
          <GivenProID>
            <xsl:value-of select="ProID"/>
          </GivenProID>
          <xsl:for-each select="Loop_Sub">
            <LoopSub>
              <xsl:for-each select="Sub">
                <xsl:call-template name="LoopCLM">
                  <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </LoopSub>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </OB_X1>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="LoopCLM">
    <xsl:param name="pos"/>
    <GivenSubID>
      <xsl:value-of select="SubID"/>
    </GivenSubID>
    <LoopCLM>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Loop_CLM/CLM[position() &lt;= $pos + $CLMGroupOccur - 1 and position() >= $pos]"/>
    </LoopCLM>
    <xsl:if test="Loop_CLM/CLM[position() = $pos + $CLMGroupOccur]">
      <xsl:call-template name="LoopCLM">
        <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos + $CLMGroupOccur"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML - Actual:

```
<OB_X1>
  <Pro>
    <GivenProID>PRO101</GivenProID>
    <LoopSub>
      <GivenSubID>SUB101</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM101</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM101N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM101N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM102</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM102N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM102N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB101</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM103</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM103N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM103N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM104</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM104N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM104N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB102</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM201</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM201N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM201N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM202</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM202N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM202N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB102</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM203</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM203N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM203N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB103</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM301</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM301N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM301N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM302</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM302N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM302N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB103</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM303</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM303N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM303N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM304</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM304N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM304N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB103</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM305</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM305N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM305N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
    </LoopSub>
  </Pro>
  <Pro>
    <GivenProID>PRO102</GivenProID>
    <LoopSub>
      <GivenSubID>SUB202</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM201</CLMID>
          <nextfield1>CLM101N1</nextfield1>
          <nextfield2>CLM101N2</nextfield2>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
    </LoopSub>
  </Pro>
</OB_X1>
```

Desired Output XML:

```
<OB_X1>
  <Pro>
    <GivenProID>PRO101</GivenProID>
    <LoopSub>
      <GivenSubID>SUB101</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM101</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM101N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM101N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM102</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM102N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM102N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB101</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM103</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM103N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM103N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM104</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM104N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM104N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB102</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM201</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM201N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM201N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM202</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM202N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM202N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB102</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM203</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM203N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM203N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB103</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM301</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM301N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM301N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM302</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM302N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM302N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB103</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM303</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM303N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM303N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM304</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM304N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM304N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
      <GivenSubID>SUB103</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM305</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM305N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM305N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
    </LoopSub>
  </Pro>
  <Pro>
    <GivenProID>PRO102</GivenProID>
    <LoopSub>
      <GivenSubID>SUB202</GivenSubID>
      <LoopCLM>
        <CLM>
          <CLMID>CLM201</CLMID>
          <OutFreqQual>CLM101N1</OutFreqQual>
          <OutFreqID>CLM101N2</OutFreqID>
        </CLM>
      </LoopCLM>
    </LoopSub>
  </Pro>
</OB_X1>
```

Any idea, how to replace `<xsl:copy>` by specific target fields. Appreciate any help

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest adaptation to your current approach would be to add a template that matches `CLM` elements and does the appropriate renaming:

```
<xsl:template match="CLM">
  <CLM>
    <xsl:copy-of select="CLMID"/>
    <OutFreqQual><xsl:value-of select="nextfield1"/></OutFreqQual>
    <OutFreqID><xsl:value-of select="nextfield2"/></OutFreqID>
  </CLM>
</xsl:template>
```

and then replace the `copy-of` with `apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Loop_CLM/CLM[position() &lt;= $pos + $CLMGroupOccur - 1 and position() >= $pos]"/>
```

The same approach would work as a modification of [the alternative solution to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28453690/592139).